# Seeding data with rails 5 with multiple belong_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist

  include Filterable
  
  validates :user, presence: true
  
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  
  resourcify
end
```

How would I be able to seed data that has multiple `belongs_to`?
Here is my method but it gives me an error of user cannot be blank

> user = User.create! :name => 'Bobby Joe', :email => '20@gmail.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password'
>
> artistOne = user.artists.create!(artist_name: 'ED', first_name: 'Edgar', last_name: 'Degas', email: 'edgardegas@yahoo.com', password: 'password', street: '2625 Ashcraft',city: 'San Diego',state: 'CA',zipcode: '92103',website: 'www.edgardegas.com',sales: '',phone: '(760)210-1326')
>
> galleryOne = artistOne.galleries.create!(name: 'Exhibition of Art', website: 'www.ExhibitionOfArt.com', phone: '(619)264-8402', opening:'10:00:00', closing:'18:00:00', street:'325 15th Street', city:'San Diego', state:'CA', zipcode: '92101')

Comment: do you have field user_id in Artist model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add associations which you created (artistOne, user),

> galleryOne = artistOne.galleries.create!(name: 'Exhibition of Art', website: 'www.ExhibitionOfArt.com', phone: '(619)264-8402', opening:'10:00:00', closing:'18:00:00', street:'325 15th Street', city:'San Diego', state:'CA', zipcode: '92101', `artist: artistOne, user: user`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your relationship id in your Gallery creation like that :

`galleryOne = artistOne.galleries.create!(name: 'Exhibition of Art', website: 'www.ExhibitionOfArt.com', phone: '(619)264-8402', opening:'10:00:00', closing:'18:00:00', street:'325 15th Street', city:'San Diego', state:'CA', zipcode: '92101', user_id: user.id, artist_id: artistOne.id)`